# Error #2036: Load Never Completed when loading an external SWF in iOs device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, remote-access

I've been fighting this problem for a couple of days without any progress so far.

I'm trying to load an external remote swf in an iPad device.

Here is the thing, I got this error: "Error #2036: Load Never Completed" when I try to load an external swf file into my project, however, in the simulator and in web it works just fine.

I'm using Flash Builder 4.7 and I've tried using Air 3.7 and now I'm with 3.8 beta, same error.

Do you have guys any idea of something I could try to make this work?.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the external swf have code in it? If I remember correctly you can't load swf files that have code in them. You are only allowed to load asset swfs.

Comment: Indeed, the remote loading of swf files that contain ABC code is not allowed in iOS, so, that raise a question, how do I check if the swf has ABC code in it?, since I don't really know, the swf files are just animations, the ABC code "could" be removed if necessary.

Comment: What mode are you packaging the application the application with? Try to compile a debug SWF and package it as `ipa-debug`. If the problem is ABC code, then you should see a meaningful error popup. You can't use the ABC stripping feature added in AIR 3.7 to load your SWF remotely.

Comment: I was using ipa-test, but I changed the target to ipa-debug in the Customize launch menu and ran the app again, same error and no popup.

Comment: I just got confirmed that the swf files have code inside, so I guess that's the problem, however, it didn't show up the message you mentioned, I'm testing on an iPad 2 thou.

Comment: New update, it seems like the error is beign generated by another error, something about multiple domains not allowed when I load the file.